# Dataproc Serverless for Spark Batch runs into a timeout after 4 hours

Tags: batch-processing, serverless, jobs, dataproc

How can I increase the time limit?

Logs show "Found 1 invalidated leases" and "Task srvls-batch-d702cb8b-1d45-44d2-bf2e-6bf6275f66bf lease grant was revoked, cancelling work."

Tried researching the properties but couldn't find any for time limit.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option called `ttl` which [defaults to 4 hours](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/quickstarts/spark-batch#dataproc_serverless_create_batch_workload-gcloud) under Dataproc Serverless runtime 2.1:

> **`--ttl`**: You can add the `--ttl` flag to specify the duration of the batch lifetime. When the workload exceeds this duration, it is unconditionally terminated without waiting for ongoing work to finish. Specify the duration using a `s`, `m`, `h`, or `d` (seconds, minutes, hours, or days) suffix. The minimum value is 10 minutes (`10m`), and the maximum value is 14 days (`14d`).
>
> - **1.1 or 2.0 runtime batches**: If `--ttl` is not specified for a 1.1 or 2.0 runtime batch workload, the workload is allowed to run until it exits naturally (or run forever if it does not exit).
> - **2.1+ runtime batches**: If `--ttl` is not specified for a 2.1 or later runtime batch workload, it defaults to `4h`.

You can set it under the [`ExecutionConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/reference/rest/v1/EnvironmentConfig#ExecutionConfig) part of the batch -> environment config -> execution config -> ttl.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent the whole day struggling with it. This kind of information should be on https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/batches/submit/pyspark#--ttl :)